# jQuery extending image portfolio under image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a extending thumbnails portfolio working the same as Google Images. Using this jquery

```
$('.thumbs a').click(function(e) {
hideNotInUse();
var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
$('.about div').eq(tmp_div).show();
});

function hideNotInUse() {
    $('.about div').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    }
hideNotInUse();
```

I started with http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7y5/ and added pictures to the mix (later I'll add video's and style everything) > http://jsfiddle.net/RvMouche/ruj3358s/

It works fine if you're using a fullscreen desktop windows, you have four images next to each other and if you click on one the assigned div shows. However if you're using a smaller window one or more of the pictures move down (expected) and the assigned div shows under the last images while it should show under the image itself.

Also, if the picture is clicked a second time, it should hide the div

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Looping over a jQuery collection to just call a basic method on each individual element is redundant. `$('div').hide()` will already hide all the elements in the collection. See this quick [example](http://jsbin.com/fubale/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Google Images sets this up is *far* more complicated than what you have going on here. If you poke around for a bit with your dev tools you'll see why.

All the image containers in the list are given a width dynamically as the window resizes, and based on some kind of break point this ends up being `N` pictures per 'row' at different window sizes. Knowing that there are `N` pictures in each row, when you click on an image they find the `Nth` picture in that row (aka the last one) and place a large `block` level element after it, disrupting the `inline-block` level elements' flow. This creates a space for the information to fill. When the window resizes, and the 'row' size changes, they shift the panel around to the end of the new 'row'.

The problem with your code is that your `.content` elements will *always* be positioned after the entire list, instead of placed at the right parts inside the list.

I'm going to ignore the dynamically sized rows for now, as it over complicates the example, and focus on the `HTML` structure, and finding and appending aspects.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/xavuhe/1/edit?js,output)</kbd>

We start by clicking an `.item`. We get the index of our `.item` in the 'list' of `.item` elements, and remove any existing display panels. If our index is the same as our previously clicked index we just set the recorded index to `null` and do nothing else. Otherwise, we take our index and recursively find the end of the 'row' with help from our modulo-remainder operator. With this new index we can target the last `.item` in the 'row' and place a `block` level panel after it.

This a very basic example in comparison to Google Images, but it is fundamentally the same logic.

```js
var displayElement = $('<div />', {
      class: 'display'
    });

var findEnd = (function () {
  var rowSize = 4;
  
  return (function (idx) {
    if (idx <= rowSize) return rowSize;
    
     if (idx % rowSize !== 0) {
       return findEnd(idx + 1);
     } else {
       return idx;
     }
  });
}());

var itemClick = (function () {
  var currentItem;
  
  return (function (e) {
    var self = $(this),
        index = self.index('.item'),
        end, target;
    
    $('.display').remove();
    $('.item.active').removeClass('active');
    
    if (currentItem !== index) {
      end = findEnd(index + 1);
      target = $('.item').eq(end - 1);
      
      self.addClass('active');
      target.after(displayElement.text(index));
    
      currentItem = index;
    } else {
      currentItem = null;
    }
  });
}());


$('.item').on('click', itemClick);
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {

  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% / 4 - 3px);
  height: 80px;
  
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.item.active {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

.display {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Note: Above I use the terms list and row very loosely, indicated by the quotes. Not to be confused with actual `<ol>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, and `<tr>` elements. This example doesn't contain true list or table elements.*

Comment: Thanks, this helps me a lot! Just one question, I need to fill the display div with information of course but I don't so how I can target the display for let's say the third element. Could you help me out there? :)

Comment: You can look through the [API](http://api.jquery.com/) for methods like: [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), but this is becoming more of a lesson on general [DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) and getting off-topic from the original question which was more about layout structure than anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your links, found it. Used 'if (index == 1){target.after(displayElement.html("some html"));}' for now :)